# How to proxy traffic from one NIC to another?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, routing, adapter

is there any basic proxy server software for Windows that allows you to setup a proxy server on one network interface (NIC/Adapter, etc) and have it route traffic through to the other network interface as if it's being sent from the second interface?

Example:
NIC1 tries to send traffic to Google.com via a software based proxy server on 127.0.0.1:9090
Software proxy sends the traffic out to Google.com through NIC2.

**EDIT**

I go to Starbucks a lot, and I like to use their free wifi. However, I would prefer to send specific types of traffic over my tethered phone's 3G connection instead of over the Starbucks network.

Comment: The two Titans have spoken already, but yes, it's technically possible... we're just not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: Hi Gravy, see my response to Chopper's answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You could do what you're trying to do with Squid Cache and the `tcp_outgoing_address` configuration parameter (which I've used on Windows and works fine) but, as Chopper3 says, it's probably better for you to explain *why* you're trying to do that instead of just asking for what you want to do.

Edit:

You could use ACLs in Squid to define the particular list of sites that need to be sent out the other tcp_outgoing_address. This is a bit of a heavyweight solution for your own local machine but it's certainly feasible to do.

This isn't necessarily a Server Fault-type question, but it's possible that somebody could want to do something similar in a corporate LAN setting.

I've got a Customer site where, for example, accesses to some web sites through a proxy server need to be stamped with a "special" source IP address (by way of the `tcp_outgoing_address` directive an an authentication ACL that back-ends to the Active Directory) depending on how the authentication occurs (to allow a rather "dumb" upstream proxy server to know that the user is of a given "class" designation when accessing these web sites).

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your response, see my comments below Chopper's response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sooner hear what you're actually trying to achieve here as what you're describing either makes little sense, is a router or is a simple matter of defining static routes. Can you come back with much more detail please.

Comment: hi Chopper, I can elaborate a little more.  I go to Starbucks a lot, and I like to use their free wifi.  However, I would prefer to send specific types of traffic over my tethered phone's 3G connection instead of over the Starbucks network.  Ideally, I could create a local proxy so that I can use a web browser for whatever traffic I want to send over my phone and another browser for Starbucks-bound traffic.

Comment: Ah ok, well firstly this isn't the best forum for this kind of question, that would be our sister site superuser.com, secondly this is easier to do via static routes.

Comment: I don't know if static routes would be easier or would work for that matter, maybe policy-based routing, but it all depends on what he means by "types of traffic".

Answer (score 0):

Like Evan suggested, setup Squid on your Windows machine using the `tcp_outgoing_address` to direct localhost traffic out through the 3G network interface.

To control what sites going out through Squid**, you could use something like [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2464/), a FireFox add-on, that allows you to configure your proxy settings on a per-domain/URL basis, so that when you want to direct traffic to a certain domain or URL out through your 3G connection, you'd add it to the list in FoxyProxy's settings.

** there may be a method of pairing the `tcp_outgoing_address` with a URL whitelist directive in Squid, but I'm not certain.